# Dataset Scala Spark: How to filter dataset if column value exists in list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to filter a dataset to see if any names in the forenames column match a given list of names.

I have a dataset "A" that includes forename and surname and want to have a typed list to match. I currently have

```
val namesToTest = List("Madeleine","Sarah");
A.filter("A.forename contains in namesToTest").show()
```

I get the error:
`mismatched input 'in' expecting {<EOF>, '-'}`

Any help is appreciated, I am new to using datasets

*(MUST be dataset solution, not allowed to use dataframes for this exercise) *

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` with `Lambda function`. In the case of a complex filter, you could create your own filter Function too. It's quite simple, write a Function that takes each value of a Column as input, then return True with your own condition. It's called `udf function`, a function that work with Spark DS or DF.

The idea is from name like `"Sarah"` create a List like `List(S, Sa, Sar, Sara, Sarah)` then check if `forename` is in that List. For example `"Sa"`, or `"Sara"` in that List

Still not sure if it's what you actually want. But you could modify your custom `udf function` too.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object test extends App{
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  case class Person(forename: String, surname: String)

  // Your list
  val namesToTest: List[String] = List("Madeleine", "Sarah")

  // Create original Dataset for testing
  import spark.implicits._
  val people = Seq(
    Person("John", "Doe"),
    Person("Sarah", "Smith"),
    Person("Alice", "Jones"),
    Person("Madeleine", "Brown")
  ).toDS()

  // Filter with lambda function
  val filteredPeople = people.filter(p => namesToTest.contains(p.forename))
  filteredPeople.show()
//  +---------+-------+
//  | forename | surname|
//  +---------+-------+
//  | Sarah    | Smith |
//  | Madeleine| Brown |
//  +---------+-------+

  // For more advance filter, you could create your our filter function too
  // It's called udf function. The "lambda function" aboved is some kind of udf fucntion too
  // BUt it's a shorted handed way to write it

  // Create a custom Filter Function. Which iterate through each forename in the DS
  val FilterFunc =  (forename: String) => {
    var result = false
    for (name <- namesToTest) { // For each name in nameToTest "Sarah", "Madeleine")
      var subStringList: List[String] = List()
      for (i <- (1 to name.length)) {
        // Create a List contain combination of name like List(S, Sa, Sar, Sara, Sarah) or
        // List(M, Ma, Mad, Made, Madel, Madele, Madelei, Madelein, Madeleine)
        subStringList = subStringList :+ name.substring(0, i)
      }
      //println(subStringList)
      // If forname in that List, for ex "Sara" is in List(S, Sa, Sar, Sara, Sarah)
      // Then return True (result (which originaly is False) || True => True)
      result = result || subStringList.contains(forename)
      //println(result)
      //println("------------")
    }
    //println(result)
    // Return final result
    result
  }

  // Turn it into udf function so that it can be used in Spark DF/DS
  val udfFilter = udf(FilterFunc)

  // Create a new Dataset for testing the UDF function
  val people1 = Seq(
    Person("John", "Doe"),
    Person("Sarah", "Smith"), // pass
    Person("Sara", "Smith"), // pass
    Person("Sa", "Smith"), // pass
    Person("arah", "Smith"), // not pass
    Person("Alice", "Jones"),
    Person("Madeleine", "Brown") // pass
  ).toDS()

  // Filter column forname with new udf function
  val filteredPeople1 = people1.filter(udfFilter(col("forename")))
  filteredPeople1.show()

//  +---------+-------+
//  | forename|surname|
//  +---------+-------+
//  |    Sarah|  Smith|
//  |     Sara|  Smith|
//  |       Sa|  Smith|
//  |Madeleine|  Brown|
//  +---------+-------+
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What if it is not an exact match, so say if I type "Sara" will it still match on "Sarah" for example?